# Audio streaming through MediaLive server

Tags: amazon-web-services, audio, streaming

I want to have live audio streaming and broadcasting setup. I would stream audio from laptop or mobile through Altacast/rtpmic or any cast to inputs of AWS Elemental MediaLive Input.

I setup AWS Elemental MediaLive Input (RTMP) and then had a AWS MediaPackage configured ahead of it. I created endpoints from MediaPackage.

I tried streaming audio from rtpmic to a IPv4 address and port number provided that I got from Elemental MediaLive and tried to hit the endpoints (output) that I got from MediaPackage. But I keep getting "error 404" at the endpoints. I have also setup channels which takes up input from MediaLive output. And the channels have endpoint which I am trying to check for output.

Where do you think I might be going wrong? How can I investigate if Inputs of Elemental MediaLive is getting Audio? Cant I use AWS Elemental MediaLive for audio streaming?

I am new to this, so please excuse me if I am stating anything incorrectly or not providing any information correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I spoke with chat support of AWS Media Live, and I understand that they havent created Elemental MediaLive for audio only streaming. Hence it cannot be done, what I was thinking to do. Users have tried sending black screen as video input and audio, but thats not the ideal way of doing it.

I am trying wowza now.